# Read Observable TAP pattern

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observer-pattern, c#-5.0

After much effort and research on StackOverflow -- most of which was outdated, as the Reactive Extensions code has changed so recently -- I was finally able to eliminate all the compilation errors from this Observable method reading data from a socket, and I understand this code much better than I did at first.  But not fully.  Could someone please read this back to me in English and answer two or three questions?

Is the buffered data extracted from this method (or how should it be, if I have it wrong)?  Are there parts of it that are no longer needed? And although I really like the decoupling from my business code, and keeping all the socket code in just one or two methods, is there a better way to do this (decoupled AND readable)?

```
    public static IObservable<int> WhenDataReceived(this Socket socket, int byteCount, SocketFlags flags = SocketFlags.None)
    {
        Contract.Requires(byteCount > 0);

        return Observable.Create<int>(
            observer =>
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[byteCount];
                int remainder = byteCount;
                bool shutdown = false;

                return Observable.Defer<int>(() =>
                        Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(socket.BeginReceive(buffer, buffer.Length - remainder, remainder, flags,
                        (result) =>
                        {
                            var read = (int)result.AsyncState;
                            remainder -= read;

                            if (read == 0)
                                shutdown = true;
                        },
                        null), socket.EndReceive).ToObservable())
                    .TakeWhile(_ => remainder > 0 && !shutdown)
                    .TakeLast(1)
                    .Subscribe(
                        observer.OnNext,
                        ex =>
                        {
                            var socketError = ex as SocketException;

                            if (socketError != null
                                && (socketError.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.Disconnecting
                                    || socketError.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.Shutdown))
                            {
                                observer.OnCompleted();
                            }
                            else { observer.OnError(ex); }
                        },
                        observer.OnCompleted);
            });
    }
}
```

The function that calls it still has compilation errors I don't understand (.Do and .BitConverter have some invalid arguments):

```
        static IObservable<string> StartClient(this IObserver<ScanInformation> observer, IPAddress ip, int port)
    {
        var client = Observable.Using(
            () => new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp),
            socket =>
            from _ in socket.WhenConnected(ip, port)
            from message in
                (from first in socket.WhenDataReceived(4)
                 let length = BitConverter.ToInt32(first, 0)
                 from message in
                     Observable.If(
                         condition: () => length > 0,
                         thenSource: from second in socket.WhenDataReceived(length)
                                     select Encoding.UTF8.GetString(second, 0, length),
                         elseSource: Observable.Return<string>(null))
                 select message)
                .Repeat()
                .TakeWhile(message => message != null)
            select message);

        return
            client.Do(observer).TakeLast(1);
    }
```

Comment: Please post your compilation errors.

Comment: Error 15 'System.IObservable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Do' and the best extension method overload 'System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Do<TSource>(System.IObservable<TSource>, System.Action<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: ...and...
Error 13 The best overloaded method match for 'System.BitConverter.ToInt32(byte[], int)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the compilation errors are due to passing incorrectly typed parameters.

Your compilation error on Do() is because your observer is an `IObserver<ScanInformation>` but the client is an `IObservable<string>`. Did you mean to convert the string to an instance of `ScanInformation`?

You compilation on BitConverter accepts a `byte[]` as the first paramter (the byte buffer to convert), but you are passing an `int` Presumably at some point you were returning the Buffer from WhenDataReceived; right now you are passing back the number of bytes read.

Rx hasn't changed so much that this sort of code would break. Your code looks to have suffered some copy/paste errors perhaps - to the point that it's probably more confusing than helpful. Have a [look at this blog post](http://www.cachelog.net/using-reactive-extensions-rx-tpl-for-socket-programming/) for a reasonable looking implementation of a socket read that uses Rx to wrap TPL calls in a fairly straightforward way. [This discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c62e690-2c8d-4f32-8ec4-5e9b5ea6d2a0/using-reactive-extensions-rx-for-socket-programming-practical?forum=rx) may also be enlightening.

There is also a pretty good `ObservableSocket` in the Rxx library. See [here](http://rxx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Networking&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: Thank you very much, but... I read those two posts and many others; I included the non-compiling code, though unfixed, only to make the purpose of whenDataReceived clearer to the reader, since it is not clear to me.  What does it say/do?  I tried for a long time to make it return the buffer but could not get it to compile and do that.  Example code I searched out to help gave errors due to .While -> .TakeWhile, and obsolete code.

Comment: The purpose of WhenDataReceived appears to be to asynchronously read `bytecount` bytes from the Socket `socket`, potentially taking multiple reads to do this. It returns the number of bytes read on each read, and sends an OnError if it fails to read bytecount bytes or some other exception occurs. The buffer is ultimately thrown away. It is a curious implementation. I'd stick with the blog post I referred you to above. For futher help, I suggest asking narrower questions, as it is unclear where your confusion lies: Rx, TPL, Socket programming or async coding in general!

Comment: I want the method to read bytecount bytes and return the buffer.  What changes would make that happen?

Comment: On the train, but try replacing `observer.OnNext` with `_ => observer.OnNext(buffer)` and change the method return type to `IObservable<byte[]>`.

Comment: Oh and `Observable.Create` will need to be of type `byte[]` too.

Comment: These worked, thanks, and now it is more clear to me that my trouble has to do with reading Rx code in the LINQ style.  That is, your suggestions made it clear to me what was happening.  Accepted as answer.